# Provide an exception class and message as arguments to raise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I'm doing some code clean up and I keep getting this offense in Rubocop. It applies to this section:

```
def load_user
 @user = OtherUser.friendly.find(params[:id])
 raise Other::NotFoundError.new('user') if @user.blank?
end
```

I thought I could simply put in a rescue ArgumentError above the raise but that did not resolve it. How do I address the exception class?

Edit:
Changing it to

```
raise Other::NotFoundError, 'user' ? if @user.blank?
```

Results in unexpected token kDEF on the next line and then unexpected token $end for the end.

Comment: Is Rubocop asking you to use the implied constructor notation, `raise Other::NotFoundError, 'user'`? `raise` will call `new` for you.

Comment: Provide an exception class and message as arguments to raise.
    raise Other::NotFoundError.new('user') if @user.blank?. Specifically underlining raise to user

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your revision contains an unnecessary '?'.

Try this:

```
raise Other::NotFoundError, 'user' if @user.blank?
```